# how to create master page in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am new for ASP.Net application. Now I want to create a website. How to create master page and how to insert table (template).

Please see this link: http://www.keystream.se/index.php

I expect this format simple website. Tell me how to create it step by step. I am using Visual Studio 2010 software in my system.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project in the solution explorer and select **add new item**. In the template that open select master page and specify a name for your master page and click **add**.

[image]

Comment: ok how to insert table in master page now i am using visual studio 2010 software

Comment: @Bala:You can just use Table control in the toolbox.You can use Gridview even to populate date.

Comment: ok please see this link  http://www.keystream.se/index.php and then tell me.... can u tell me how to create this format website step by step can you help me...

Answer (score 1):

Add Item:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The link given by @x2 is more than enough for you to understand on how to use master pages.

But if u wanna know here are the steps you need to follow.

1) First is obviously to decide a theme or a template that u wanna have in your page.

2) Then Add a master Page to your project as shown by @Darin Dimitrov .

3) Decide on what area of the page will be frequently changed and which of them will be a static ( You can still change them in code).

4) Then Design the Master page accordingly. and add an content place holder like this.
     `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PageContentPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` .  This will be the place holder for the contents of the usual aspx pages.

5)Remember if you wanna aply themes you need to set `EnableThemeing` attribute to true and then set the Theme in the aspx page.